# Create External Content Type - Access denied by Business Data Connectivity

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, bdc, sql-server-2012

Following the technet articles on how to get external data into SharePoint 2013 (for testing purposes) I've created:

- Business Data Connectivity Service with Metadata Store Permissions
- Secure Store Service Application (SSS) with SQL Server credentials (and not windows credentials, since they fail too)

The credentials in SSS are owners of the database *Northwind* I'm trying to connect to. When signing in with SQL Server Credentials, the user can read and execute the database as expected.

[image]

In SharePoint Designer I'm adding the new External Content Type, providing it a name and database server, database and connecting with Impersonated custom identity referencing the SSS. When I provide the SQL Server Credentials, it fails to connect asking for windows credentials. But since windows credentials don't work on the SQL Server login either, I'm stuck in a loop I can't get out of.

Error from SharePoint Designer

[image]

Error from SQL Server Log

[image]

The Web Application has service connection to BDC, and in the Secure Store Service Application *Everyone* is member. Still - no connection made because of the access denied error. Why is that, and how do I overcome this issue?

Comment: check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/06/11/access-denied-by-business-data-connectivity.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I haven't been able to create the ECT yet, so I've been there reading too without any luck.

Comment: But did you "set the permission on a metadata store"?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yep! My first bullit in the question says so. All according to the TechNet series https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683106.aspx

Comment: oh sorry, i overlooked it.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE No worries! I've been reading blogs for two days with this one. Just glad you're trying to help :-)

Comment: thank you, i am sure then same account under which you trying to create having the permission their....just doubleschecking

Comment: even MSFT KB saying the same thing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982271 ...i would say try with different account,

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Do I need to create a business data connectivity App within the BDC service app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, I needed to configure an External Content Type Profile Page Host within the Business Data Connectivity Service.

[image]

[image]

When the ECT Profile Page Host was configured, I could connect to the database and see the tables from the database within SharePoint Designer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Designer does not use the Secure Store connection. Try creating the ECT first by connecting with user's identity. Once the ECT is created, modify the properties to use the Secure Store application ID.

Comment: I tried this too, with individual credentials using on attempt one Windows credentials that has DB access, and secondly with SQL Server user credentials. I got different error logs in the SQL server, but still no connection. Do I miss a setting in the BDC Service Application?

Answer (score 1):

I had to grant Metadata Store Permissions:

Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications > BDC Service Application

- click **'Set Metadata Store Permission'**

  [image: Set Metadata Store Permission]
- then add your user and permisisons

  [image]